# Python - Passing a list as argument to class

Tags: python, list, class, arguments

So, I have the following code:

```
locations = [0,1]

class Draw:
    def __init__(self, locations):
        self.locations = locations

    def platforms(self):
        print(self.locations)

Draw.platforms(locations)
```

And the terminal gives me:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'locations'
```

Is there a specific way to pass a list as an argument? I'm new and I don't understand why it works with a int argument but not with a list.

I want to know why this is happening and what can I do about it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Draw(locations).platforms()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling the method "platforms" which is not expecting you to pass it a parameter, and are passing it a parameter. The "locations" list is actually passed to the constructor method of your class, which gets called when you instantiate it. Your "platforms" method is called without parameters and prints it.

Here's how you should (probably) do it:

```
locations = [0,1]

class Draw:
    def __init__(self, locations):
        self.locations = locations

    def platforms(self):
        print(self.locations)

draw = Draw(locations)    
draw.platforms()
```

Comment: No worries. Also, just as a heads up, the whole point of classes is to make objects to represent things in your code. The way you've named things is kind of weird. You have a class called "Draw" (a verb) and a method called "platforms" (a noun.) What would probably make more sense is to name the class after the noun and name the method after the verb. class Platforms, method draw. Classes are objects. Methods are actions to be performed with those objects. Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

This could be done with whats called a *static method*.

```
locations = [0,1]

class Draw:
    def __init__(self, locations):
        self.locations = locations

    @staticmethod
    def platforms(variable):
        print(variable)

Draw.platforms(locations)
```

> ```
> [0, 1]
> ```

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing at the moment is calling `platforms([0, 1])`, which then attempts to resolve
 `[0, 1].locations`.  That's what your error is telling you: `list`s don't have `locations`.

You need to create a `Draw` object, with a list argument.  You can then call the `platforms` method of that object:

```
draw = Draw(locations)
draw.platforms()
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
locations = [0, 1]

class Draw:
    def __init__(self, locations):
        self.locations = locations

    def platforms(self):
        print(self.locations)

Draw(locations).platforms()
```

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand why it works with a int argument but not with a list.

No, it doesn't:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "method.py", line 10, in <module>
    Draw.platforms(locations)
  File "method.py", line 8, in platforms
    print(self.locations)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'locations'
```

The reason why it doesn't work in either case is because you never constructed any instance of your class---you just called on a ("public") method belonging to the class. So when `platforms()` tries to use `self.locations`, it doesn't exist.

You could either instantiate the object first:

```
locations = [0, 1]

drawer = Draw(locations)
drawer.platforms()
```

Or, if you don't care about keeping the `Draw` instance around:

```
locations = [0, 1]

Draw(locations).platforms()
```

Or you change the method so that it accepts an argument instead:

```
class Draw:
    def platforms(value):
        print(value)
```

But now it's basically a static method, and you're only using the class as a namespace.